# Usar valores passados de uma Activity para outra

Tags: android, listview, intent

Galera, estou tendo dificuldades em uma certa coisa. Eu criei uma lista onde mostra os nomes de contatos, porém esses contatos possuem mais atributos, como data e número. Fiz outra tela para quando a pessoa clicar na lista, ir nessa outra tela e mostra todos os detalhes de tal contato. Eu fiz tal codificação. (Estou usando SQLite para salvar/utilizar os contatos) caso isso seja relevante
Na tela de detalhes dos contatos, eu fiz isso:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact__detail);

    long idSelected = getIntent().getLongExtra("ID", 0);
    long positionSelected = getIntent().getIntExtra("POSITION", 0);


    textView_dName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_dName);
    textView_dDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_dDate);
    textView_dNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_dNumber);

}
```

Minha dúvida é: Como eu faço para os textviews receberem os valores passados? Por exemplo: textView_dName.setText tal tal tal. Peço ajuda por favor com tal código, desde já agradecido!

**EDITADO**

Classe **DBHelper**:

```
public final static String DATABASE = "mydb";
public final static String TABLE = "contacts";
public final static String NAME = "name";
public final static String DATE = "date";
public final static String NUMBER = "numberr";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists "+TABLE+" (id integer primary key, "+NAME+" text, "+DATE+" text, "+NUMBER+" text)");


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public boolean insertContact(String name, String date, String number){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(NAME, name);
    content.put(DATE, date);
    content.put(NUMBER, number);
    db.insert(TABLE, null, content);
    return true;
}

public ArrayList<Contact> getAllContacts(){
    ArrayList<Contact> myArray = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    while(cur.isAfterLast()==false){
        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.setName(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(NAME)));
        c.setDate(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DATE)));
        c.setNumber(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(NUMBER)));
        myArray.add(c);
        cur.moveToNext();
    }
    return myArray;
}

//

public Cursor getAllContactss(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur1 = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE, null);

    return cur1;
}
```

**MainActivity**:

```
DBHelper myDb = new DBHelper(this);
Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllContactss();
String[] columns = new String[]{
        DBHelper.NAME,
        DBHelper.DATE,
        DBHelper.NUMBER
};

int[] to = new int[]{
        R.id.textView_l1,
        R.id.textView_l2,
        R.id.textView_l3
};

ListView listView_contacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_contacts);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.layoutdalist,
            cursor,
            columns,
            to,
            0);

    listView_contacts.setAdapter(myAdapter1);




    listView_contacts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Cursor cursor1 = (Cursor) listView_contacts.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String nome = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NAME));
            String data = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.DATE));
            String number = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NUMBER));
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Contact_Detail_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("NOME", nome);
            intent.putExtra("DATA", data);
            intent.putExtra("NUMERO", number);
            startActivity(intent);
           /* Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Contact_Detail_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ID", id);
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);
            startActivity(intent); */
        }
    });



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_item_new_contact:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewContactActivity.class));
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

```
    DBHelper myDb = new DBHelper(this);
    ArrayList<String> arrayNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < myDb.getAllContacts().size(); i++){
        arrayNames.add(myDb.getAllContacts().get(i).getName());

    }

    ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayNames);
    listView_contacts.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: Sua dúvida seria em relação ao `TextView` receber os valores ou como fazer para você buscar esses dados no SQLite?

Comment: Minha dúvida é como que eu faria para settar os dados que eu armazenei nos intent nos textviews da outra activity. Espero que entenda, acho que seria em relação ao TextView mesmo

Comment: Mas na sua pergunta já está a resposta, basta você utilizar a função que você disse: `textView_dName.setText("texto recebido");`. Os passos seriam pegar sua variável `idSelected` que está vindo na Intent, consultar no banco o contato com está identificação e passar os dados através do `setText` do `TextView`, seria isso?

Comment: Hmm, você poderia me explicar como eu consultaria no banco usando a `idSelected`? e dar o `setText` com o resultado?

Comment: O id que mostra no adapter não é o id no banco, você precisa criar um Adaptador que armazene esse ID ou fazer um HashMap pra ligar o ID X ao Id do item no adaptador.

Comment: Se possível, mostre como você popula essa ListView, daí fica mais fácil sugerir como implementar essa questão

Comment: Uma outra opção é usar um SimpleCursorAdapter, neste caso o ID no item será o _id da tabela.

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro Eu editei a minha postagem e coloquei mais informações sobre o programa. Coloquei a classe `DBhelper` que tem um método de população e a `MainActivity` que tem um método de repopulação também. Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem diversas formas de você conseguir o que quer, eu utilizaria um SimpleCursorAdapter.

Ele funciona da seguinte forma, ao invés de você passar uma lista de Strings para popular a ListView, você vai passar direto o Cursor, desta forma, ao selecionar um item você pode acessar qualquer informação daquele registro (que você tenha incluído na query inicial é claro).

Então vamos a implementação.

**Classe DBHelper:**

```
public Cursor getAllContacts(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE, null);

    return cur;
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
DBHelper myDb = new DBHelper(this);

 Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllContacts();

String[] columns = new String[] {
NAME
};  // Coloque o nome das colunas que você deseja exibir


int[] to = new int[] { 
  R.id.textViewName   
  }; // Colocar o ID da textview que você vai utilizar pra mostrar os dados (Se for mais de um, só acrescente , entre um e outro, o mesmo com as colunas)

SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter= new SimpleCursorAdapter(
this,  // Contexto
R.layout.meu_layout_itens, // O layout que será inflado para comportar os itens (crie um xml com um Root Element como um Linear Layout e coloque um TextView nele, estilize como quiser, só não esqueça de usar o mesmo id que você usou acima)
cursor,           // Seu cursor
columns,          // Nome das colunas do banco
to,              // Views que receberão os dados
0);              // Nesse campo você pode usar uma Flag para ativar outras funções do Adapter, como auto atualizar ou registrar um Observer (Não vamos entrar nesse mérito aqui ainda) 


listView_contacts.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

E no seu **ClickListener:**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position); // Recupera o cursor na posição escolhida
        String nome =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NAME")); // Pega o item que deseja de dentro do cursor

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Contact_Detail_Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("NOME", nome); // Envie tudo que precisar, repita com outros campos necessários
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Não esqueça de criar o arquivo de Layout

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela resposta. Só algumas dúvidas sobre essa implementação. `String[] columns = new String[] {
NAME
};` Ali onde tem o NAME eu colocaria as colunas feitas no DBHelper, certo? e colocaria tipo "name", "date", "number" e na `int[] to = new int[] { 
  R.id.textViewName   
  };` eu colocaria R.id.textView_dName, R.id.textView_dDate, R.id.textView_dNumber? Eu já tenho a Activity com os detalhes das pessoas, ela possui esses 3 `TextView`

Comment: `R.layout.meu_layout_itens, // O layout que será inflado para comportar os itens (crie um xml com um Root Element como um Linear Layout e coloque um TextView nele, estilize como quiser, só não esqueça de usar o mesmo id que você usou acima)` aqui eu coloquei o meu activity com detalhes do contato, que contem o textView_dName, dDate e dNumber. Correto?

Comment: Onde vai `NAME`  você usar a variável do DB Helper mesmo, as Colunas que você quer exibir, quanto ao Layout, antes você estava inflando o `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` esse é um layout padrão do Android, porém, você não tem acesso aos TextViews que ele usa, então você cria um Layout próprio, com as TextViews que você quer usar, e no `int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textViewName }` você coloca o ID dessas views. Isso serve somente pra você mapear, dizendo que aquele item do String vai para aquela View.

Comment: O layout que você usa para a Activity tem outras coisas juntas certo ? O ideal é você usar uma layout só para os itens. Então seria um LinearLayout>TextView|TextView|TextView. E isso será repetido para cada item da ListView

Comment: Entendi, acabei de criar uma Layout e coloquei 3 `TextView`nelas. Onde você falou para colocar a variavel do DBHelper, eu não posso colocar a variavel NAME lá, fica vermelho. Acho que não tenho acesso a variavel da DBHelper fora da classe. Então eu coloquei "name" que é o que esta na variavel NAME, outra dúvida, como eu vou recuperar esses valores na minha classe Contact_Detail_Activity?

Comment: Se as variáveis forem private você não vai conseguir usar elas mesmo, se for public tem que importar a classe. Para recuperar os dados, você pega os "extras" que você está mandando no Intent

Comment: Opa, desculpe te encher novamente Lucas, eu fiz o que você pediu, acho que estou no caminho certo, porém, meu app tá dando errado assim que abre, eu editei a postagem como ficou o código depois das alterações. Eu fiz certo? Obrigado novamente

Comment: @Viskee Qual mensagem de erro dá ?

Comment: Oi Lucas, eu consegui resolver o problema usando seus métodos. Fiquei dando uma mexida ali e aqui e resolvi. Obrigado pela sua ajuda e pela paciência.